# Path of Log file

Tags: provider-hosted-app, log

I have a provider hosted app where the exception logs are logged to a text file. The path of the text file is calculated as below :

```
string directoryName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string rootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string strFilePath = rootPath + directoryName;
```

There is a client webpart which displays the provider hosted website in an iframe. On button click, an exception is occuring.

I want to know what will be the value of `rootPath` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) property gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.

```
//Getting the Base directory of the application.
            string rootPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            Console.WriteLine(rootPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to know if I can find the file in the SharePoint farm or the farm where the website is hosted

Comment: did you run the writeline and saw what path it is mentioned? i think this path is where app ishosted

Comment: For the console app, the `rootPath` is pointing to the bin folder. I searched the bin folder of hosted app and it was not there..